# How to convert CSS3-based HTML to image

Tags: php, linux, image-conversion

How can I convert a CSS3 or CSS2-based HTML page into a JPEG or PNG (with transparent background) image?

Is there any command-line tool or php-based API that can be installed on my Linux server and provide me with the best result possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/. Check downloads sections, there is a `wkhtmltoimage` package.

It uses WebKit rendering engine, so your certificate should only look good in Safari/Chrome.

P.S.

Python with Qt4.4 required, but luckily most Linux boxes have python (and probably Qt as well, at least mine does)

Example of running `./wkhtmltoimage-i386 --crop-h 450 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096068/how-to-convert-css3-based-html-to-image/11096920#11096920 output.png`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make a picture of what the page would look like in a browser, you need an HTML rendering engine (one of a browser's main parts) for that.

PHP doesn't have one of those built-in, but you could use an external program like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to do the rendering.

Comment: I have a html based certificated dynamically created by users by filling up a form. i need to send his certificate's screenshot into his email where i need to convert this html certificate into an image

Comment: Why not just send the certificate as HTML?  Most email software supports it.

Comment: yes you are right, but not every email provider and clients supports it. We have already tried but display in every email providers and in every client are different..

Comment: You can also include a URL, in the email message, to load the certificate from the server.  People using email software that doen't support HTML can copy the link into their browser.

Comment: actually this is a clients requirement so cant suggest him alot, rather will ask for extra fund ;)... thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

I used [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) command line tool under Windows. It is of course cross-platform.

Comment: i want something like, but for LINUX?

Comment: As I wrote it is cross-platform, you can install it on linux. There are instructions on their website.

Comment: it can be my last option if we didn't found anything. :) thanks anyway